# Andorid: how to create a non erasable custom notification in the statusbar?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I just want to make a custom notification on statusbar that remanis there during user interaction.

I use this code:

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(getBatteryStateResource(percent,status), "notify",System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.statusbar);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent=contentIntent;
    notification.contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, anotherContentIntent);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(42, notification);
```

This code work only on android 4 smartphones. On tablets, every time I click on the imageView of the notification, system delete notification.

Instead, on Android 2.3 and 2.2 the "anotherContentIntent" don't start and start only "contentIntent", why??

many thanks at all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FLAG_NO_CLEAR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR) in addition to `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`.